# How to find out who is locking a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm running `show processlist` and see a lot of similar queries to one particular table (btw it has myisam engine) in state `Locked`, I just want to figure out which one query stucked all others, because when i'm killing 1st from top of the list (ordered by spending time) it does not help :(

Is there any possibility, to figure out, who is the reason of soooo long queue ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check **Time** column on show processlist result, the one with highest value for Time column should be the query which is locking the table

Comment: but problem is the "oldest" query is not related with target table totally, how it could be ?